# Python: Dictionary: Based on the key provided return an initialized class object variable

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm new to learning python.

I'm in a situation where I have many classes, e. g.:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, entry):
        ...

    def printf(self)
        print "A"

class B:
    def __init__(self, entry):
        ...

    def printf(self)
        print "B"

class C:
    def __init__(self, entry):
        ...

    def printf(self)
        print "C"
```

Next, what I wish to do is to have a dictionary, like this:

```
OBJECT_LIBRARY = {'A': A(), 'B': B(), 'C': C()}
```

So, when I refer to the dictionary with a 'KEY' the dictionary should return an **initialized object** of that type.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If classes don't have initialization variables, then

```
OBJECT_LIBRARY = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}

OBJECT_LIBRARY['A']()
```

In case you have initialization variables, then you could do something like this

```
OBJECT_LIBRARY = {'A': lambda : A(a, b), 'B': lambda : B(b, c)} # assuming a, b, c are defined

OBJECT_LIBRARY['A']()
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain why lambda is required in the second case?

Comment: It makes the `dict` values callables that can be used to create an object with a set of fixed constructor arguments. It's not strictly necessary to use `lambda`s to get that effect; `functools.partial(A, a, b)` would work similarly to `lambda: A(a, b)` (though it would still allow you to call the resulting callable with additional arguments) if you prefer to use the batteries instead of reinventing the wheel with `lambda`s.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define the dictionary with references to the class (rather than the object) and then define the object when you refer the dicitonary?

Example -

```
OBJECT_LIBRARY = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}
```

Then you would use it like -

```
OBJECT_LIBRARY['A']() #Or other classes as needed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `OBJECT_LIBRARY = {'A': A(), 'B': B(), 'C': C()}`, it is just storing the objects (rather creating new object). Instead, store the functions which will *create* and init the objects. Like this:

```
>>> class A(object):
    def __init__(self,entry):
        self.entry = entry

    def printf(self):
        print "A", self.entry


>>> class B(object):
    def __init__(self,entry):
        self.entry = entry

    def printf(self):
        print "B", self.entry


>>> object_library = {'A':lambda:A('a'), 'B':lambda:B('b')}
>>> new_and_initialized_A = object_library['A']()
>>> new_and_initialized_A.printf()
A a
```